The messages are not getting rendered for the single chat. from the backend the data is retrieved but in here it is not getting rendered
This is the ui page for one to one chat
This is the code:
const ScrollableChat = ({ messages }) => {
  const { user } = ChatState();

  return (
    <ScrollableFeed>
      {messages &&
        messages.map((m, i) => {
          (
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }} key={m._id}>
              {(isSameSender(messages, m, i, user._id) ||
                isLastMessage(messages, i, user._id)) && (
                <Tooltip
                  label={m.sender.name}
                  placement="bottom-start"
                  hasArrow
                >
                  <Avatar
                    mt="7px"
                    mr={1}
                    size="sm"
                    cursor="pointer"
                    name={m.sender.name}
                    src={m.sender.pic}
                  />
                </Tooltip>
              )}

              <span
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: `${
                    m.sender._id === user._id ? "#BEE3F8" : "#B9F5D0"
                  }`,
                  marginLeft: isSameSenderMargin(messages, m, i, user._id),
                  marginTop: isSameUser(messages, m, i, user._id) ? 3 : 10,
                  borderRadius: "20px",
                  padding: "5px 15px",
                  maxWidth: "75%",
                }}
              >
                {m.content}
              </span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </ScrollableFeed>
  );
};

export default ScrollableChat;

If I type some message and click enter the request is sent to backend and it is getting stored in DB and even in the frontend it is fetched. but the message is not getting rendered.

Does messages variable have data?

Yeah messages variable has data. I'm sending a request to backend and getting the data and setting the message state to the response data.
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
const { data } = await axios({
url: http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/messages/${SelectChat._id},
method: "get",
headers: {
Authorization: Bearer ${user.token},
},
responseType: "json",
});
setMessages(data);
I checked using console.log(messages) after setting messages state to data, I'm getting output and correct response from backend.

You can do {console.log(m)} to check if the current message has data inside the loop. I think the problem is the isSameSender or  the isLastMessage.
